# IDbCommandInterceptor interceptionContext.SuppressExecution() is not suppressing query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So I'm attempting to use interceptionContext.SuppressExecution() to prevent an update from writing to the database under certain circumstances.  Despite setting a result and calling SuppressExecution().  The update command is still executed.

```
public class ExampleInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{

    public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        interceptionContext.SuppressExecution();
        interceptionContext.Result = 1;
    }

    // Omitted the entire implementation
}
```

Comment: Is one of the other ..Executing methods called.  EF might be use a batch that returns data to do the update.